# Why a value of a variable doesn't change inside backticks?

Tags: shell, variable, command-substitution, variable-substitution

Here's my test code:

```
a=1
echo $a
echo `let ++a`
echo $a
```

The output that I see is `1`, `1`. Why doesn't the third line modify the value of `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `...` equivalent to $(...), which is a subshell. changing variables in subshell are lost when the subshell closes.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a variable like this:

```
a=1
((a++))
echo $a
2
```

Which is more like "C-style" incrementing, instead of:

```
let a++
```

See Ipor Sircer's answer as to **why** your method didn't work!